# Cassandra effective ownership is less than 100%

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have been running Cassandra in two data centres with 6 nodes each. Recently, I had to upgrade the hardware and I just wanted to start it off by adding the new node and removing the existing node. I started off with increments of three as I have three three groups in each data center. Previously, effective ownership was split equally in two data centres - it was 50-50. Post adding three new nodes and removing the existing three nodes, I find the effective ownership to be 50--49.9. I would like to know if something is wrong with respect to my cluster. I don't understand how this gets unbalanced now.

Cassandra version used : 2.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely a rounding error and you shouldn't be too worried about it (Especially for a %.1 difference). The actual ownership should be keyspace dependent since you should be using `NetworkTopologyStrategy`.

Try calling nodetool status keyspaceName to see how your keyspaces are actually distributed amongst the cluster. This will also take into account the Replication Factor of the keyspace so you'll get an accurate picture of how a particular keyspace is replicated throughout your entire cluster.